# Difference between "unlikeable" and "dislikeable"?

Tags: meaning, differences, adjectives, negation, prefixes

Is there a difference between *unlikeable* and *dislikeable*? It feels like there is, but I'm uncertain how to explain it.

Comment: The same as the difference between any un-word and dis-word. There is no special significance to likeable in relation to the use of the un- and dis- prefixes.

Comment: @Kris and what is that general difference?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assume there are three states of fondness for something.

- Like
- Neither like nor dislike
- Dislike

Disliking something is *not* the same as not liking something. If I don't like peas, I will eat them with no pleasure. If I dislike peas, I will actually find them nasty.

So, *dislikeable* is something that's easy to dislike.

*Unlikeable* is something that's difficult to like.

Comment: My interpretation.  *unlikeable* ... you cannot fall into the first group, "like".  *dislikeable* ... it is possible to fall into the last group, "dislike", but perhaps also possible to fall into the other two groups, instead.

Comment: @slim thanks for the answer. It's useful to point out that 'dislike' is not the same thing as "not like". However, to me the word unlikeable implies that something is impossible to like, not merely difficult.

Answer (score 1):

According to the definitions of *[unlikeable](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unlikeable)*:

> Adj. 1. unlikeable - (of characters in literature or drama) tending to evoke antipathetic feelings; "all the characters were peculiarly unsympathetic" 
>    2. unlikeable - difficult or impossible to like; "a disagreeable and unlikable old woman"

and *[dislikeable](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dislikable)*:-

> Definition: easy to dislike

the difference would appear to be that an *unlikeable* thing is something you don't or can't like, and a *dislikeable* thing is something you could quite easily not like (but that you have no particular aversion to at the moment).

Comment: thanks Brian, but sorry it's still a bit unclear to me. On one hand, we have "difficult to like" and on the other "easy to dislike"!

Comment: @BrianFenton, I think slim has put what I was trying to say, rather better.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, it seems pretty straightforward.
Unlikeable - 'Not likeable' (Not necessarily negative, just straddling the fence. Infrequent usage)
Dislikeable - 'easily hated' or 'easily vilified'

Unless you mean the new 'unlike'-able, which is a sad result of the FB culture and not a real word.

Comment: Thanks but I don't fully agree with you. Unlikeable to me is a strongly negative term, implying impossibility of liking.