# Is there a difference between "dislike" and "don't like"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

A friend of mine for whom English is a second language told me that I am the only person he knows who uses the word "dislike", and asked me what the difference was from saying that I "don't like" something. I answered that they were the same, but that "dislike" might be more formal... but it occurred to me that I was not totally confident with this answer.

Is there a difference between "I dislike that" and "I don't like that" besides the former being more formal?

Comment: I don't think there is any real difference between the two.

Comment: I think they are slightly different. "*Don't like*" may convey indifference but "*dislike*" stresses on hate.

Comment: "don't like" is merely an absence of liking.  "dislike" is fairly mild, but still it entails the presence of negative feelings.  "I don't like pistachio ice cream" is milder than "I dislike my sister's new boyfriend." it's all part of a continuum.....don't like, dislike, disdain, abhor, detest, can't stand, hate.....  Check definitions of these words, and of others you might find alongside them in a thesaurus.

Comment: The problem is that `don't like` is two words and difficult / impossible to find in a dictionary. I also personally use `don't like` to mean `dislike`, but maybe I'm using it wrong.

Comment: I only use *dislike* with nouns. For example, I don't like to ski, but I dislike skiing. And [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=don't+like%2Cdislike%2Cdon't+like+to%2Cdislike+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdo%20not%20like%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdislike%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdo%20not%20like%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdislike%20to%3B%2Cc0) shows that lots of other Americans have the same usage constraints.

Comment: I have an extreme don't like of "dislike".

Comment: There is not much of a difference in most cases, but there is a CLEAR difference in some. We dislike the same things.
We don't like the same things. These two sentences have opposite meanings. But for most cases, dislike is just a bit harsher.

Comment: To me "don't like" means that I do not enjoy it, i.e. would not prefer to have it, but that I will still have it, whereas dislike means that I actually don't want it at all and will not have it.

Answer (score 8):

Saying that you **dislike** something means you *have a distaste for* or *hostility towards it*.

When you **don't like** something, it means that you would *prefer something else over it*. You would want *this* to not happen.

*Source*: Apple's dictionary.

'Don't like' means that even though you would prefer the *other thing* you can still adjust to *this* happening. But saying that you 'dislike' means that you will be really unhappy if the thing that you disliked, happens.

**Update:** Happen to find [another similar question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55425/difference-between-unlikeable-and-dislikeable?rq=1).

Comment: Please use italic for mentions.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: In a matter as important as of liking someone it would be better to be clear and contextualize properly. Otherwise we can just say 'don't like' and keep the zero option open.

Comment: I'll correct my comment. CGEL does say that the pragmatics of the situation are that a bald 'Mary doesn't like you' implicates 'Mary dislikes you', and that the "zero option" 'would normally [be expected to be contextualised. To give an example,]' 'Mary doesn't like you, but she doesn't dislike you either' is an acceptable use of the "zero option". So OP's question needs really needs to be better defined.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Got you. Agreed.

Answer (score 5):

Just as in logic, negation affects only the constituent it modifies, but in logic, negation can modify only sentences, whereas in English, it can modify other constituents as well.  (A logician might prefer to call negation an "operator" rather than a "modifier".) The constituent modified by negation is called its "scope". Syntacticians test for where the scope of negation is by constructing examples with polarity items, positive and negative (see [the Wikipedia article on polarity item](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarity_item)).

As your intuitions probably suggest, in "dislike", negation modifies only the verb "like", but in "doesn't like ...", negation modifies the entire verb phrase.  Accordingly, positive polarity "somewhat" is permissible after "dislike" because it is not within the scope of negation,

```
I dislike snails somewhat.
```

but negative polarity "at all" is not permissible,

```
*I dislike snails at all.
```

"Don't like" is opposite, since the entire verb phrase is the scope of the negation:

```
*I don't like snails somewhat.  
 I don't like snails at all.
```

The definitive syntacticians' reference to negation and scope is Larry Horn's [A natural history of negation](http://emilkirkegaard.dk/en/wp-content/uploads/A-natural-history-of-negation-Laurence-R.-Horn.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

**Dislike** is stronger than **don't like**. **Don't like** is passive; it's an absence of liking. You could for instance be neutral or disinterested. **Dislike** is active. It means you expressly *do not* like it and are therefore by definition not neutral about it.

If you imagine a scale going from dislike at -1 to like at 1, "don't like" is in the middle at zero. Or at the very least it refers to the entire part of the scale between -1 and 0, inclusive.

Comment: You know, when I say *I don't like John*, it's quite a bit stronger than mere absence of liking.

Comment: @PeterShow That depends on the emphasis. If you say *I don't* like *John* it could mean you don't dislike him either.

Comment: 'Don't like' takes a range of values from -1 to 0, and thus is sometimes as strong in indicating revulsion as 'dislike'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: In my answer I myself wanted to explain it using -1, 0 and, 1 but refrained from it as people are not always in the same mindset and therefore miserably fail to appreciate any such explanation attempts. For me, I know exactly what you mean.

Comment: @PepijnSchmitz: Dislike = -1, Like = 1, Don't like implies not 1, therefore can be 0 (i.e. indifferent) or -1 (i.e. dislike).

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the context. "Don't like" can be interpreted in the same way as "dislike" e.g. "I **don't like** ice cream" is the same as "I **dislike** ice cream". They both mean I don't like any kind of ice cream.

In other cases, the two can have very different meanings e.g. "I **don't like** all flavours of ice cream" vs "I **dislike** all flavours of ice cream". Here, by using "don't like" I imply that I like most flavours of ice cream but there are a few that I don't. On the other hand using "Dislike", tells you, as with the first example that there are no flavours of ice cream I enjoy.

Answer (score 2):

The only non-obsolete meaning that the *OED* finds for "dislike" is "not to like," so I think it's safe to say there's no difference.

Comment: If that's _all_ OED has to say, displayName seems a better bet.

Comment: The *OED* also comments that the word is "the opposite of like" and provides six historical usages over 300 years or so.  Notwithstanding displayNames' opinions about options, specificity, what "people use," comparative softness, and the dire consequences of misusing "dislike," my money remains on the *OED*.  YMMV.

Comment: Remember that OED is not always the best arbiter of current usage. I certainly agree with displayName that 'I don't like ...' is ambiguous (from 'I dislike ...' or worse* to 'X is not one of my favourites'.  (ODO, a more frequently updated Oxford dictionary, lists as synonyms of 'dislike': hate, detest, loathe, abominate, abhor, despise, scorn, shun, execrate ... But this may be going too in far the other direction.)

Comment: No source is always the best arbiter of current usage, and I'm willing to be convinced by evidence of a difference between the two locutions.  displayName's opinion, even heralded in bold, just isn't enough to change my bet.

Comment: [5jj on Using English.com/forum](http://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/151633-Don-t-like-and-dislike) comments wisely, with a good example:
Re: **Don't like and dislike** <<
Most of the time there is no big difference; we tend to use 'don't like' when 'dislike' might be expected. We possibly use 'dislike' in more formal contexts.

It is possible to use 'don't like' with the simple idea of 'absence of liking'; but we then usually add a few words to make our meaning clear: "I don't (really) like Indian food, but I don't (actually) dislike it"..>>

Comment: I became familiar with the "wise" first person imperial pronouncements of 5jedjon and the rest of the Royal Family on Englishforums.com.  They didn't cut any ice with me there, and they don't here.  Once readers encounter the claim that there's no difference in meaning (fussily presented as "no big difference") and bat away a couple of "possibles," they find themselves in the realm of personal usage, signaled by the necessity of additional words like "actually" and "really," meaning that actually, the words in question are really synonyms.  I'll let my bet ride.

Comment: Which version of OED are you citing? When was the relevant article last updated?

Comment: [Not exactly the Royal Family.](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/47991552252041389/)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The original print version.  The supplements have not entries for "dislike."  I have no access to the online *OED*.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth About the Royal Family: we are very amused, mostly because I think it makes my point about a nonstandard usage that requires that an explanation be attached.  But see my next comment.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Here endeth my participation in the lesson.  I seem to have become one of those people I complain about, the internet jerk who must have the last word on everything.  Not that seeming and being aren't congruent.  Be that as it may, there's no need to advertise quite so insistently.  Let me end graciously by saying that you and dName have a valid point, and that I have been too dogmatic in my gainsaying.  And by "graciously," I trust you understand that I mean "without even a hint of sincerity."

Comment: The 'original print version' dates from 1884-1928.

Comment: Last print supplement for A-G, 1972.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine it like so:

```
Word                                | Emotion as number         | Example
------------------------------------|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Love                                |  2  (max. positive value) | I love it!
Like                                |  1                        | I like it
(none)                              |  0                        | No comment / It's ok / I've no feeling towards it / 50-50 / etc
Dislike                             | -1                        | I dislike it
Hate                                | -2  (max. negative value) | I hate it!
```

Notice none of the 4 words above (far left column) are negated. Negation happens by adding "don't" before the word. Examples:

- I don't love it.
- I don't like it.
- I don't dislike it.
- I don't hate it.

When you use negation, it doesn't necessarily mean the opposite, it just mean it could be ANY other feeling.

- `I don't like it.` actual emotion could be "I love it!".
- `I don't like it.` actual emotion could be "It's ok".
- `I don't like it.` actual emotion could be "I dislike it".
- `I don't like it.` actual emotion could be "I hate it!".

Words in any language depends on context, so the meaning of a word may change, and also they way we say/express it.

**Range:**

`I don't like it, but I don't hate it` is a range expression which is between no-comment and dislike. So rating this feeling in mathematical equation could be like so:

-2 < Emotion < 1

So could be -1.9 ... 0.9

---

**Answering the Question** (`Dislike vs. Don't Like`):

`Dislike` = -1

`Don't Like` = ANY number that's not 1 (could be 2, 0, -1, -2), so it's *ambiguous* statement, which could be clearer by context + the way it's said/expressed/sounded.